# Python: BeautifulSoup .find_all() prints empty []?

Tags: python, class, parsing, beautifulsoup, findall

I'm trying to grab forecasted high/low temp from wunderground with this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib2 import urlopen
zipcode = raw_input("Type in your zipcode: ")
url_end = zipcode + ".1.99999"

base_url = "http://www.wunderground.com/weather-forecast/zmw:" + url_end

my_html = urlopen(base_url)
html_text = my_html.read()
my_soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text)

high = my_soup.find_all("span", class_="high")

low = my_soup.find_all("span", class_="low")

print high
```

It'll ask your zip, you give it, it should spit back all forecasted high/low temps as are displayed on the webpage, however I'm new to BS4 and I'm clearly messing something up with the `.find_all()` because I just get back empty brackets:

```
[]
```

I'm plenty aware I will need to clean up the results once operational.

Comment: why is there `_` after `class`? Is that typo?

Comment: @Anzel that is the syntax of BS4 for naming conflict reasons.

Comment: Ah cool, usually I use dictionary and avoid kwargs, cheers. By the way, does the site block requests without **user agent**? check your `html_text` response, and you may trying adding one and see.

Comment: Doesn't block requests, I can change the high = my_soup.... bit to something like print my_soup.title or another tag name and it works.

Comment: @CharlesWatson, can you show the partial result in `html_text` where the `span` with class `high`/`low` and ensure they exist?

Answer (score 2):

The webpage is being updated with javascript and so the results are not within the page elements.

With how the site works it might be better to use a split and json, or do some more in depth analysis on the site to find the call that is being used to return the data for the javascript framework that is being used on the site.

Or just use the api: http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/d/docs?d=data/geolookup#zip_or_postal_code

Basically it is empty because the javascript updates the elements on the page.

You could however use something like selenium to open the page and run the javascript.

And then your call would work as you expected it to.